# ng-change on uib-datepicker-popup is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

ng-change on uib-datepicker-popup is not working

Code in my html -

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ng-focus="myFocus(123)" ng-change="mychange(987)"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Code in my controller -

```
  $scope.myChange = function(para1) {
    console.log("myChange -- "+para1);
  }
```

Expecting mychange function to trigger whenever user types in a different date or when he uses the picker to select a date.

Plunker link - https://plnkr.co/edit/e20qSViEAh9dZ6GEFnVh?p=preview

Comment: `myChange` is not `mychange`,

`ng-change="myChange(987)` should work.

Comment: ah yes. thanks for pointing it out.